# Expressing Integer Matrix in the form $\begin{bmatrix} r & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, modular-forms

Suppose $A\in \mathrm{M}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ has determinant $r\neq 0$. I want to show there exists matrices $M,N \in \mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $$A = M \begin{bmatrix}r & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} N$$

Since $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $S= \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 &0 \end{bmatrix}$ and $T  = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, we can find $M_1\in\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ such that $M_1A$ is upper triangular. Then you can conjugate by $S$ to get a lower triangular matrix. Repeat the above process to get matrices $M_2,N_2$ such that $M_2AN_2$ is diagonal. But I don't know how to finish it off. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: As pointed out in the comments. Unless $A$ is primitive (gcd of the entries is 1), the statement is false since the Smith Normal Form is unique. If we suppose that $A$ is primitive, can I finish the above argument?

Comment: See also [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form)

Comment: Could you expand? Based on your first question, is it necessary that $\gcd(a,b,c,d)=1$? Why is this necessary

Comment: By hypothesis $A$ has determinant not equal to 0, so this counterexample doesn't work.

Comment: Using the tools of Smith normal form that lhf linked to, you can prove that with the additional assumption that $\gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1$, then indeed the desired conclusion holds.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel Schepler for explaining.

Comment: lhf's original counterexample $A=2I_2$ can now be revived as a valid counterexample. Applying yout operations to $2I_2$ will not change the $\gcd$ of the entries, which is $2$, or the determinant, which is $4$.